# she has been good?

Tags: grammar, present-perfect

There's a scenario like this : We are in the hospital. our friend is lying in the hospital bed. everything is going well and then he suddenly collapses. at that time the doctor comes in and asks us what happened and I'm saying this :

I don't know. **she has been good ?**

I don't know. **she was good ?**  Which one is true ? Can you also give some examples about **'' has been ''** independent of this example?

Comment: How do you collapse if you are already lying down in bed? And how did he become she?

Comment: Did you mean the patient  **was totally fine** before **going into** cardiac arrest / seizing / stroking...? you can't collapse if you're already lying. You should use a dictionary and check the meanings of words.

Comment: I think saying [going into seizure](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22going+into+seizure%22&oq=%22going+into+seizure%22&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUyBggAEEUYOTIKCAEQABgPGBYYHjIKCAIQABgPGBYYHjIICAMQABgWGB4yCggEEAAYDxgWGB4yCAgFEAAYFhgeMgoIBhAAGA8YFhgeMgoIBxAAGA8YFhgeMgoICBAAGA8YFhgeMg0ICRAAGIYDGIAEGIoFMg0IChAAGIYDGIAEGIoF0gEIMzU5MmowajmoAgCwAgA&client=ms-android-samsung&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8) is probably a more accurate description.

Comment: I'm confused. You say "**he** suddenly collapses" then you say "**she** has been good". Why the change in gender?

Comment: I don't think 'good' is even the right adjective to use here, although it's become common in an exchange like "How are you?" "I'm good." I don't think you should begin the interrogative sentence with "She has been...?" either, but "Has she been..."

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to be about the tense to use.  But there are many problems with the rest of the words being non-idiomatic that it is hard to say which tense is right.

Instead of "good" you need a different word or phrase.  Perhaps the simplest would be "fine".  Now since the patient isn't fine now, you should use a past tense "He was fine".

But if you are explaining to the doctor, there might be more story, and a past perfect might fit better:  "He collapsed five minutes ago, he had been fine until then".

Instead of "fine" a native speaker might use a wide range of expressions which are either more precise or more general:  "He'd been doing well".  "He was conscious", "He'd seemed to be improving". But not "He was good".